# Command line - query account type (local, network managed, mobile)

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, command-line-interface, apple

How can I query account type information. Things like `who` and `users` don't show this. Also tried things like `dscacheutil -q user`

I'd like to know if a users account is a mobile account and I am doing this through SSH, inevitably I'd like to make a script so any network managed account can be made a mobile managed account using this command I found to make a current user's account a mobile account `sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/ManagedClient.app/Contents/Resources/createmobileaccount -n userid -v`

Any thoughts on how I can query that information? Account types I am aware of are Local, Networked Managed and Mobile Managed, but I cannot find any way to get this information via CLI.

Comment: Not sure but perhaps the dscl command can help you? I've not tried this before but it can do a lot with Directory Services query and commands. Good luck I'm curious about this too now.

Comment: @bispymusic Unfortunately, I have tried quite a bit with `dscl` and nothing has been fruitful in providing the information I'm looking for. `dscl . readall /users` seems to give the most information overall as well, but still nothing of what I want. Thanks for the thought. I will keep everyone posted, if I find a solution. Still looking for one...

Answer (score 0):

If it's AD, you can use dsconfigad to see if the settings are set correctly

> dsconfigad -show | grep Create\ mobile\ account

As for finding out if current users are mobile or not, I'm in the same boat and will post if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers completely the question, but I noticed that when I set an account to be a mobile account, file $HOME/.account is created. For local accounts and network accounts, this file doesn't exist

Comment: None of my, AD bound computers, mobile accounts, have that hidden file you mention. Could have been a little helpful. Which OS version do you see this on? I don't see this on anything 10.7+